# Firebase chat - need suggestion

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a project where a chatting feature is required. For the chatting module, I am using firebase chat.

Please check my requirement
1.Ten to fifteen people chat together on a "chat group". Users can chat "one-to-one" or "group chat". This type of chat group will be created approx 1000 per day.

2.There is a live event section on our project. On that day 15,000 to 20,000 users can join a single group chat and chat together. Approx 10 live events happen in a month.

3.There is a file upload option on the chat module. Approx 20GB/day of data can be stored on "storage".

**My question is**
a)which kind of database is good for this kind of situation - "Cloud Firestore" or "Realtime Database"?
b)please suggest to me about the pricing? what will be the approx pricing for this type of chat module?

Comment: For deciding what database to use: did you see (and try) this already: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore ? For determining the cost, did you see the pricing calculator at the bottom of this page already: https://firebase.google.com/pricing?

Answer (score 0):

I have done messaging to my App and I got it working with `Realtime Database`

`Realtime Database` has `.on` future. that mean when a new value enter  the database the other user will be notified. You don't have to trigger the question to the database again and that is what `Realtime` mean.

Comment: While I'd also go with Realtime Database for this solution, the realtime listeners aren't the reason. Firestore has an `onSnapshot` method, which results in the exactly same behavior. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: I know, but realtime has faster response and it can handle more then `Firestore`. I would use both. for realtime I would only save the messages content and for `Firestore` i would save data that are complex. That is what I did anyway.

Comment: I'd clarify that bit about speed in your answer, as it now reads as if Firestore requires polling which it doesn't.